# removing wsus in sbs 2008 program features, is this a bad idea to uninstall it?

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, wsus

is there any issue with removing the windows server update services from the sbs 2008 add/remove (program features)? will it break anything else in the process like exchange or IIS etc, any updates or services packs that could cause an issue? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see why it would be an issue, just remember to remove the Group Policy properties that redirect everyones updates to the SBS 2008 machine, otherwise nobody will receive any updates.

Comment: k thanks will do, i can deal with that later, i was just wondering if for some strange reason things like outlook web access or remote web workplace might stop working. i would be shocked if something like exchange would not function correctly without wsus being present.